# Lambda timeout connecting to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-vpc

I have an S3 bucket in Account A and a lambda function in Account B. I want the lambda to read the contents from the bucket, so have assigned the appropriate permissions to the IAM role and added that IAM role to the bucket's trust policy. The lambda works fine when it is not part of my VPC, but when it is in the VPC of Account B then the lambda times out which makes me think that the timeout is due to a connectivity problem.

I have used a VPC endpoint for a different lambda to access Secrets Manager, but a VPC endpoint to connect to S3 doesn't solve the problem in this case. I have read in some places that the lambda needs a NAT/Internet Gateway in order to connect to a cross account Bucket, but AWS say:

```
By default, Lambda functions have access to the public internet. This is not the case after they have been configured with access to one of your VPCs. If you continue to need access to resources on the internet, set up a NAT instance or Amazon NAT Gateway. Alternatively, you can also use VPC endpoints to enable private communications between your VPC and supported AWS services.
```

So, simple question really: Does the lambda need a NAT/Internet gateway to access the bucket, or should the VPC endpoint be enough?

EDIT:
terraform for the VPC endpoint.

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name      = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"

  security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.lambda.id,
  ]

  subnet_ids          = [aws_subnet.subnet_1a.id]

  tags = {
    Name        = "vpc-endpoint-s3"
    Environment = var.aws_profile
    Terraform   = true
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_security_group_association" "s3" {
  vpc_endpoint_id   = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3.id
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.lambda.id
}
```

Comment: yes an endpoint is all you need. you must have not configured it properly. *but a VPC endpoint to connect to S3 doesn't solve the problem in this case.* what kind of endpoint? interface or gateway?

Comment: This is an VPC Interface endpoint. I have added the terraform for the VPC endpoint in the question now.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

A VPC endpoint is all you need to connect to an AWS service from a VPC. In the case of S3, you have the choice to choose between an interface endpoint and a gateway endpoint.

You have configured the interface endpoint incorrectly. This is the issue:

```
security_group_ids = [
  aws_security_group.lambda.id,
]
```

you are associating the security group of the lambda to the VPC endpoint, however I suspect that that security group does not allow access to itself.

Instead, following best practices, you should create a separate security group for the endpoint:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "vpc_endpoint_security_group" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  name   = "allow traffic to vpc endpoint"
  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = -1
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.lambda.id]
  }
  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name      = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"

  security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.vpc_endpoint_security_group.id,
  ]

  subnet_ids          = [aws_subnet.subnet_1a.id]

  tags = {
    Name        = "vpc-endpoint-s3"
    Environment = var.aws_profile
    Terraform   = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the lambda need a NAT/Internet gateway to access the bucket, or should the VPC endpoint be enough?

If you do  have NAT/IGW, your lambda must be in a **private subnet** with properly setup route table to NAT.

Alternatively, use VPC endpoint or do not place your function in a VPC. In that case, you do not have to do anything special to access s3.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, the VPC endpoint is sufficient only if the lambda is in a private subnet? It is currently in a public subnet, so I will try changing that. I have added the vpc endpoint terraform to the question so it can be seen.

Comment: @sobmortin If you have VPC endpoint, your lambda can be in any subnet. If it does not work, it means you have configured your VPC, vpc endpoint and/or subnet groups.

Comment: Ok I will look into that, thanks for narrowing it down. Do I need to add a route table?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I will post here for anyone who encounters the same issue.

Unlike the `VPC Endpoint` for `Secrets Manager`, the `VPC Endpoint` type should be `Gateway`, not `Interface`. The association with the Lambda therefore needs to be made via the route table, not directly on the endpoint by attaching subnets and security groups. I have the lambda in the public subnet associated with the route table now and it seems to be working.

Here is the terraform:
`vpc_endpoint`

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name      = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Gateway"

  tags = {
    Name        = "vpc-endpoint-s3"
    Environment = var.aws_profile
    Terraform   = true
  }
}
```

`aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association`

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association" "s3" {
  route_table_id  = aws_route_table.rt.id
  vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3.id
}
```

`aws_route_table`

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "rt"
    Environment = var.aws_profile
    Terraform   = true
  }
}
```

Hopefully this will help the next person

Comment: It doesn't have to be a gateway endpoint. You must have not configured the interface endpoint properly

Comment: Hmm thats very likely, can you see anything potentially wrong in the original terraform of the VPC endpoint?